# Customize gerrit home page:logo and color

Tags: gerrit

I have installed and configured gerrit, I see it has white color background instead of green like https://codereview.qt-project.org (probably changed from green to white in recent versions) but, want to know if we can customize color and add a logo.

From [gerrit-documentation](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1/config-headerfooter.html) I see we have to create below files and place them in $site_path/etc/ but, I am not sure how to create them, I am bad in HTML.

```
$site_path/etc/GerritSiteHeader.html and 
$site_path/etc/GerritSiteFooter.html
$site_path/etc/GerritSite.css
$site_path/static/logo.png
```

1. Is it possible to change the color of gerrit pages, I mean from default white to any other?
2. Please provide me the sample GerritSiteHeader.html and GerritSiteFooter.html so that I can make changes to them and use in my gerrit. I haven't used HTML before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are couple of settings to change colors in `gerrit.conf`: [theme settings](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#_a_id_theme_a_section_theme).
2. An example for our theme files we are using on [review.typo3.org](http://review.typo3.org): `GerritSiteHeader.html`:

   ```
   <h2 class="typo3-logo">
   <a href="/"><img src="/static/typo3-logo.cache.png" alt="TYPO3" /></a>
   </h2>
   ```

I won't paste our CSS file (GerritSite.css), as it won't help you a lot.

If you write down, what you want to put in the header or footer, one can help you. But when you say you don't know HTML (it's very easy..) and don't say, what you want, it's hard to tell you the exact soluation. I at least hope that https://review.typo3.org gives you an impression, how you can customize it. Finding somebody to write you 5 lines of HTML or CSS should be easy.

Comment: Thank StephenKing, This is what exactly I wanted. I was mistaken that we need to write a big HTML file for entire home page :) I could figure out sample GerritHeader.html myself, but I was not aware of "theme settings" in gerrit.conf, this helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Think docs are fine, aren't they? "HTML is inserted below the menu bar, but above any page content."

Comment: Yes, docs are very helpful. I am able to customize colors using theme setting and had Header and Footer as well. Thanks

Comment: What is the way that you placed the Logo in the same line, left to the menu bar?

Comment: CSS. `#gerrit_topmenu { padding-left: 160px; }` and `#gerrit_header { position: absolute; top: 0 }`. I suggest that you just look at that site and play a bit with your browser's developer tools (or ask sb. with some CSS knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Gerrit 3+ with PolyGerrit UI, you can no longer use `GerritSiteHeaders.html` and `GerritSite.css`

To do that, one should add a custom `.js` plugin

##### Logo

Put your logos to `/gerrit_root/static/logo.png` and your plugin to `/gerrit_root/plugins/plugin.js`

Here's a hacky example of a plugin, which adds both dark and light logos for dark and light themes respectively (there might be a better way, but this one works)

```js
Gerrit.install(plugin => {

  const domHook = plugin.hook('header-title', {replace: true});
  domHook.onAttached(element => {
    console.log(plugin);
    const img = document.createElement("img");

    if (document.getElementById('dark-theme') == null) {
      img.src = "/static/dark.png";
    } else {
      img.src = "/static/light.png";
    }

    img.height = 24;
    img.align = "top";
    element.appendChild(img);
  });
});
```

On some versions it requires to refresh page after changing the theme, but the latest versions will refresh it by itself.

##### Colors and styles

To change colors, you can override styles in the new plugin:

```js
const customTheme = document.createElement('dom-module');
customTheme.innerHTML = `
  <template>
    <style>
    html {
      // Here's how you can change default background
      --background-color-primary: yellow;
      // This is how to make header Qt Green
      --header-background-color: #41cd52;
      // You can change header's border as well
      // And you can use existing css variables
      --header-border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    }
    </style>
  </template>
`;
customTheme.register('theme-plugin');

const darkCustomTheme = document.createElement('dom-module');
darkCustomTheme.innerHTML = `
  <template>
    <style>
    html {
      // The same way you can modify dark theme
      --primary-text-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </template>
`;
darkCustomTheme.register('dark-theme-plugin');


Gerrit.install(plugin => {
  plugin.registerStyleModule('app-theme', 'theme-plugin');
  plugin.registerStyleModule('app-theme-dark', 'dark-theme-plugin');

  // LOGO related stuff from above and everything else
});
```

See some examples: [polygerrit-ui/app/samples/](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/master/polygerrit-ui/app/samples/)

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674698/gerrit-customized-homepage-does-not-work-for-new-ui-like-v3-0/59675220#59675220) with a similar answer

Comment: registerStyleModule has since been depreciated. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pg-plugin-dev.html#low-level-style recommends document.head.appendChild although I've yet to get either to work with the scoping rules they have applied on the different elements.