# customize logo on home page gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I want customize my logo on the home page gerrit.
I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307964/customize-gerrit-home-pagelogo-and-color) and created a `GerritSiteHeader.html`. But my logo location is at the bottom of the gerrit menu. I want put my logo at the top of left as in this gerrit installation at [review.typo3.org](https://review.typo3.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very unclear with your question, as you should add your own code.

I think the important part of our stylesheet at [TYPO3's Gerrit](https://review.typo3.org) is the following:

```css
 #gerrit_header {
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, my englis not good. I want my stylesheet look as TYPO3's Gerrit.

I was creat a GerritSite.css and add gerrit_header as you  suggest.
and here is my gerrit home page.
http://pik.vn/2015cd817639-0b0c-4815-aff1-ecba3c8442f3.png
can you help me solve it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That's our GerritSite.css: https://gist.github.com/StephenKing/810bf4e4b2e010d3c792

Comment: thanks you. But my location of my logo don't true as like your gerrit.
my GerritSiteHeader.html only contain: 
<h2 class="typo3-logo"> <a href="/"><img src="/static/abc.png" alt="TYPO3" /></a> </h2>
how to put it on true location?

Comment: I don't know. Either provide a link to your installation, compare the CSS in detail or ask one that helps you out with that. I don't know how to solve this by guessing. Sorry.