# gerrit customized homepage does not work for new UI like v3.0

Tags: gerrit

When gerrit version was v2.15, it was support GerritSiteHeader.html in ../$gerrit_path/etc/. But it was only work in old UI which was called GWT UI. I want to see GerritSiteHeader in new UI whch was called PolyGerrit.
  I try to upgrade gerrit version from v2.15 to v3.0, but it does not work!
  Does somebody meet question like this?
  Document: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/3.1.2/config-themes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I moved to Gerrit 3.0. The PolyGerrit UI uses plugin's, see the documentation [pg plugin dev](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pg-plugin-dev.html) page.

If you place the below file, name it my-logo.html in the /var/gerrit/plugins directory it will change your logo to my-logo.png

```
<dom-module id="my-logo">
  <script>
    Gerrit.install(plugin => {
      const domHook = plugin.hook('header-title', {replace: true});
      domHook.onAttached(element => {
        var i = document.createElement("img");
        i.src = "/static/my-logo.png";
        i.height = 32;
        i.align = "top";
        element.appendChild(i);
      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

More information can be found in this discussion [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/tgvmGhfFcgU), this is a great place to ask questions as all the Gerrit contributors hang out there

Comment: I also found the answer here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/tgvmGhfFcgU,thanks.
I want to add some notice and links to the header and footer, which endpoints can I use，i use banner as endpoints which like  ，But it doesn't look good
code like:
<dom-module>
  <script>
    Gerrit.install(plugin => {
      const domHook = plugin.hook('banner');
      domHook.onAttached(element => {
        var i = document.createTextNode("Notice:xxxx")
        element.appendChild(i);
      });
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>